# What Airfix model is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification, model-aircraft

I built this Airfix kit when I was younger, and don't know what it is. I'd love to know!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like it could be a [Mirage III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Mirage_III), but the angle of the photo makes it difficult to be sure.  Do you have any other photographs?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post with some extra photos that you can look at

Comment: I'll stick with Mirage III. There are loads of photos available on Google - take a look and see what you think.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I just had a look and found it! I’ve been searching for a good while so though I’d give this a shot, and within a few minutes I found it. Thanks again. Stay safe

Comment: Heh. I was going to disagree until I realized the reason the canopy frame is different is because yours is missing the canopy. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is a relatively early **Mirage IIIc**. You can tell it from other common modifications by the longer rear fuselage, which accommodates the longer afterburner of the older [Snecma Atar 9B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snecma_Atar) engine.

[image: Mirage IIIc box]

The exhaust nozzle on your model is closed indicating military power. On most photos you will see it wide open (it has two buckets on a hinge, and a horizontal gap is clearly visible).

I know all this because not too long ago I built a similar model, but with a smaller 1:100 scale.

[image]

Comment: Hats off to your model building skills! +1